# How do push-notifications like GCM work internally?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

Push notification services like Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) are providing a special functionality: They are able to wake-up a device which is in idle mode.

Which way is used to wake-up the device over a push-connection regarding battery-life? My first assumption was that the connection of the radio is still active even if the processor of the device sleeps. In the event of an incoming push-message the radio wakes the processor via an interrupt and starts an android intent to handle the push message.

But there a third-party push-services like "OpenPush" who offer the same functionality, which makes my assumption look incomplete or wrong. Or are those service just an abstraction for the push-systems of multiple vendors (Google, Apple) and are a bridge to the service which are integrated in a native way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My first assumption was that the connection of the radio is still active even if the processor of the device sleeps.

If by "the radio", you mean "the cellular radio", this is correct. Open socket connections over mobile data (not WiFi) can be maintained even though the CPU is in a sleep mode. Incoming packets on that connection can wake up the CPU. Google has spent quite a bit of time tuning this to minimize how much power is used keeping the socket alive (e.g., "heartbeat" packets from the device to the GCM server periodically).

> Or are those service just an abstraction for the push-systems of multiple vendors (Google, Apple) and are a bridge to the service which are integrated in a native way?

That is a common approach.

It is entirely possible for an app to try to maintain its own long-lived socket over mobile data. SIP clients do this, for example. It is tricky to get right, particularly with an eye towards low power consumption. I also worry about the reliability of this approach with some of the changes coming in Android M.

As OpenPush is remarkably not-open at the moment, I cannot comment specifically on what they are doing.

Comment: CommonsWare can you cite any sources regarding why cellular modems are able to maintain sockets and wake the CPU but not Wi-Fi? I believe that if the CPU sleeps on an Android device the Wi-Fi usually remains connected and network socket connections need not be re-established but I do not know if an incoming packet will wake the CPU. It seems it would be highly dependent on the Wi-Fi driver? Also what about ethernet?

Comment: @satur9nine: "can you cite any sources" -- I can tell you that this is what Google said, such as in Google I|O conferences where they discussed the implementation of C2DM (the predecessor to GCM and FCM). "I believe that if the CPU sleeps on an Android device the Wi-Fi usually remains connected" -- on newer devices, that may be an option, but even there it may be subject to user configuration or manufacturer changes. "Also what about ethernet?" -- I have no idea, sorry.